# "not enough players to start the match" - invite friend for 2 player game using google play API

Tags: android, google-play

I´m developing a 2-player real-time multiplayer game by using **Google Play API**. Here´s what´s happening: one player invites his friend for a match, the friend accepts the invitation, the two join a room and try to connect to each other for a long time when the following message appears:
"not enough players to start this match"

But i did put as action for the Invite Player button the following:

```
intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, 1);
```

By the documentation, it says that this is required for a 2(and only two) player game. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post all your code, specifically the code where **the two join the room**.